# Name of the following sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given $n$, $m$ (both natural numbers), I want to calculate the sum
$$\sum_{r = 0}^{n}(-1)^{r} \cdot {}^{n}C_{r}\underbrace{\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{r} + \left(\dfrac{3}{2^2}\right)^r + \left(\dfrac{7}{2^3}\right)^r + \left(\dfrac{15}{2^4}\right)^r + \cdots\right]}_{m \text{ terms}}$$

I was wondering whether there is a name of such a sum, so that perhaps there is a formula to get the answer?

Comment: @Clarinetist You go dude!

Comment: $S(n,m)\sim2^nm$.

Comment: @Lucian Sorry what is S(n,m)? This sum should be a number less than 1, right? Thanks